# ASP Error 0131: Parent Path is not allowed

Tags: visual-studio, asp-classic, iis-express

I'm trying to run an **ASP Classic** application on **Visual Studio 2013** and **IIS Express**. I'm getting the following error when running one the page:

```
Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0131'
Disallowed Parent Path
../..
The Include file '../file.inc' cannot contain '..' to indicate the parent directory.
```

I've researched the issue online and found out that the problem is related to the ../ that is disabled by default. The solution proposed is to **allow the Parent Path**. While this solution is **discouraged for security reasons**, moreover, I don't have administrative privileges to make such changes.

Is there another way to solve this problem that doesn't involve **allowing Parent Path**?

Comment: Another option is to use virtual paths...     Server.MapPath("/mywebsite/file.inc")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the alternative is to use the include virtual directive, you would have to update all paths to be from the root of the virtual directory

```
Include Virtual '/file.inc'
```

or

```
Include Virtual '/Folder/file.inc'
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way to solve this issue without modifying the code is described in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-parent-paths-are-disabled-by-default), by enabling *ASP Parent Paths* at the site configuration in the **IIS**, simple steps are:

1. go to the **ASP** feature of the site or application you want to configure *parent paths* on *IIS Manager*,
2. in the list that appears configure the **Enable Parent Paths** option setting it to **True**.